# When speaking of age 13 and over, is it 12+ or 13+?

Tags: grammar

When you take into account all ages above a certain age, what is the correct way to write it?

I was supposed to write all ages above 12, and not including 12, so I wrote '13+', which in my mind seemed to mean '13 and plus'/'13 and above'.

Someone told me it's meant to be written as '12+', but to me, this looks as if it's including the age 12 in it.

What is the correct way, when talking of all ages above but not including 12, to write it: 12+ or 13+?

Comment: Does "all ages above 12" include twelve-and-one-nanosecond? If that's the intent, then your interlocutor is right. If it means "at least thirteen, then you're right.

Comment: Non-Q! :) The question in the title has an obvious answer. Beyond which it's not about the English language at all. Voting to close.

Comment: No, all ages above 12 means at least 13 in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way, is 13+. People see that as "Age 13 and above are allowed / permitted".

Comment: When you look at children toys, they don't say 3+ for ages four and up. No, they are saying that ages 3 and up are allowed to play with that toy.

Answer (score 6):

If you're referring to something like the [MPAA's PG-13 rating](http://www.mpaa.org/ratings/how-to-read-a-rating), it *excludes* children under 13, and *includes* movie-goers 13 and over.

So yes, you would write "13+" to mean ages 13 and over.

Comment: It excludes under 13, but I'd say that does not imply inclusion for over 13 only - what happens if someone wants to view that content on their 13th birthday?

Comment: @Alok Then the law says that they're 13. (Although, apart from a school ID, I'm don't think someone that age would be carrying photo ID that lists their age in the USA. But still -- they're included.)

Answer (score 4):

13+. It's an inclusive statement. However, like all moments where there's confusion for any reason, it might make sense to use something less ambiguous, such as your own "age 13 and over".